# AndroidAnnotations @EProvider annotation

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-annotations, android-database

In my Android application I'm using ContentProvider and SQLiteOpenHelper to access DB.
Now I learning AndroidAnnotations framework and found @EProvider annotaion in documentation, but I can't neither understand how to use it from [example on GitHub](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Enhance-contentproviders) nor find using examples on the internet.
Can someone explain me using of this annotation?
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think the wiki is pretty clear. That annotation is needed to enable injecting stuff into your provider, like beans, resources, services etc.